# Asynchronous and synchronous

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

IF I used synchronous and asynchronous ajax request on the same page when page will load on browser and synchronous request is first and asynchronous is second request on page. So what will be happen there?

1. will Asynchronous request wait until synchronous request will get the data from the server.
2. Or will Asynchronous request not wait and execute as the request?

I tried to find this answer but didn't get anywhere. Please give the answer if anyone have

Comment: If you just tried it, you could probably see what happens. The answer is: the asynchronous request will wait for the synchronous to return from the server (or time out) before sending its request.

Comment: If the sychronous request didn't block the script execution it wouldn't be synchronous.

Comment: If you substitute "wait before going any further" for synchronous, and "keep on going, no need to wait for me" for asynchronous in your question, you'll see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronous means that the code that initiates the synchronous requests waits and blocks until the request completes. The calling and the called code are *"in sync"*. Asynchronous means the code that initiates the request continues immediately and the asynchronous call will complete sometime later. The calling and the called code are *"not in sync"* or *asynchronous*.

As such, if your code fires a synchronous request, it waits until that request is completed. Nothing else will happen in the meantime, so the asynchronous request won't be triggered until the synchronous one completes.

If you fire the asynchronous request first and the synchronous one afterwards, it's not necessarily clear which code will finish/execute first, since the asynchronous request may finish at any time.

Answer (score 0):

The asynchronous will take place when your synchronous request is done. So number 1.